# Microsoft Flow - Update merge fields in the flow

Tags: pdf, flow

I have a word template that is using merge fields to get the file name and version number whenever a new document is created.

[image: Document being converted but used template merge fields]

This document is put through a flow to be converted into a pdf but the merge fields of the document are not updating but instead are using the templates merge field values. Is there anyway to have merge fields of a word document be updated when put through a flow? For reference I am using the OneDrive convert document action in flow.

[image]